# new Drawable error after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After updating Android Studio I get the following error:
error: drawable() has private access in drawable
at the line:

```
R.drawable ourRID = new R.drawable();
```

It was working fine before updating Android Studio is there anything I should do to fix this error?

Comment: Did you check the import of `R` ? What is `R`?

Comment: I didn't make any import of R I think it is like R.string and R.id